# Replacing bytes to character not working

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, shift-jis

i am trying to read some text from a binary file using streamreader, the file is composed of pointers, pointing to text strings, so the text is japanese, and there are some tags around some of those japanese characters (signifying top Hiragana/Katakana over kanji, this is not important), this si how it looks like:
太一ÿBたいちÿ (91 BE 88 EA FF 42 82 BD 82 A2 82 BF FF 00)
my software can read up to where the stream reader meets a 0x00, but the "FF 00" part is only the end of the taging, and not the string, i am trying to convert the "FF 00" byte (0x00FF) to a word so it can no longer stop the streaming, this si what i try but it doesn't work:(no errors or exception, it just doesn't)

```
string Strs = Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS").GetString(sttrings).Replace("\uff00","<et>");
```

am i wrong in some part ?

Comment: how special the end point is? I mean the `0x00`, is there any data to read after it?

Comment: `am i wrong in some part` I am sure, yes. if it is a binary data, then you shouldn't use *streamreader*. If it is a text file then you shouldn't need those tricks.

Comment: KingKing King: here is the full string, 太一ÿBたいちÿ …… (91 BE 88 EA FF 42 82 BD 82 A2 82 BF FF 00 81 63 81 63 00) the last 00 is the end of the string, only a 00 without an FF behind it can be considered as an end to the string.
I4V: it possible to use streamreader and binaryreader, the difference is how to use, im pretty sure i am not wrong in the coding part but in teh replacement only.

Comment: @Omarrrio `im pretty sure i am not wrong`, If you were right you wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: What about the `00` between this `FF 00 81`, how could your code pass by that to continue reading?

Comment: I4V: it's not the code im wrong in, but the replacement, everything works fine, the reading and all, but the 0x00 is the one holding me back.
@KingKing: the FF 00 (ÿ) is the end tag of the hiragana, i thought i could replace those two bytes to show as something inside of the textbox like <et> (end tag) for example, but i can't seem to be able to do so.

Comment: @Omarrrio What you don't get is: every text file is actually a binary file, but the every binary file can not be safely converted to text. You are on the wrong track. But anyway, It is your problem. Go on....

Comment: @I4V: i never said it was a text file, it is a binary file, like with functions and stuff, as i said in my topic post, the file is more of a script, each string has a pointer pointing to it's offset, how do i calculate the length of the text ? i just take the next pointer and retrieve the previous from it (Pointer[i+1] - Pointer[i]).

Comment: @Omarrrio the principle is you have to provide some special token or at least some special algorithm to detect the end point correctly without missing with any other normal data bytes. You don't need to replace, just think of how to detect the end point, it depends on your data and your way of reading.

Comment: @KingKing: you see, the C# binary/stream reading process, always stops at any 0x00 (depends on the encoding, if unicode then it's 0x0000), im just gonna try to put a special encoding(the way you showed me is a little complicated and i couldn't do it).

Comment: @Omarrrio if so `00` can't be the token to stop reading, you have to append some kind of special token (when writing file) to mark the end of string.

Comment: @KingKing sadly im not the one who writes the file, i only edit it.